# Redis publish object from node.js

Tags: node-redis, node.js, redis

На сервере Node.js имеется клиент redis:

```
redisDummyPublishClient = redis.createClient();
redisDummyPublishClient.publish('478669c7fa549970e36eac591cdca62e', {'nameChannel' : 'questions', 'title' : 'Как улететь?', 'text' : 'Обратитесь к пилоту!' , 'id' : '2', 'time' : datetime});
```

Здесь постится сформированный JSON на канал редиса.
При прослушке каналов редиса, в качестве **dataJson** получаю не объект, а строку вида: **[object Object]**

```
 redisClient.on('pmessage', function(pattern, channel, **dataJson**) {
    CreateSocketsAccept(channels_active, channel, **dataJson**);
  });
```

ЧТО НЕ ТАК ДЕЛАЮ?

Comment: а кто вам сказал что туда можно объект отправлять, а не сообщение ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отправляйте в паблиш строку - объект, сериализованный через JSON.stringify, а при получении сворачивайте эту строку в объект через JSON.parse